# Saving TensorFlow Keras model in custom algorithm container for SageMaker estimator fails with permission error on deploy endpoint

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, amazon-sagemaker

The custom algorithm container trains a Tensorflow Keras model, and after it finishes training I save the model:

```
model.save('/opt/ml/model')
```

The training jobs finishes successfully, but when I try to deploy the `sagemaker.Estimator` made from the custom algorithm container, I get the following error:

> tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.PermissionDeniedError:
> /opt/ml/model/variables/variables_temp; Read-only file system
> [Op:SaveV2]

It fails on the `model.save` line.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned here : [Github Issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/13120)

The problem is caused by that you save the model file in the same path which you put the Python file.

Try saving the model file in a different path from the path of python file.

Hope this works for you.

Comment: The model is saved on /opt/ml/model and the code is under /opt/program so they are already in a different path. I tried with different paths but the problem persists.

Comment: Try saving the model in other path than /opt/ml/model

Comment: The model has to be saved under `/opt/ml/model` , because that is where the Sagemaker looks after the training has finished and packs the model and uploads it to s3. If I change the path to be different I get the error `Could not find model data at s3://sagemaker-{region}-{id}/output/{image}-2021-10-10-12-13-59-407/output/model.tar.gz`

Comment: Did you try to add sudo before writing the command?

Comment: Yes , I tried to run it as root user, but I get the same error

Comment: Could you please post the command that you've executed?

Comment: `RUN groupadd -r admin && useradd -r -g admin admin

USER admin`
this is inside the docker file